# Some basic Javascript to suggest a pricing

Tags: javascript

I have code that currently will give a `DayPrice`, an `ExtraDayPrice` and a `WeekPrice` based on the `ItemValue` that was entered by the user.

```
$("#ItemValue").change(function () {
    var val = parseFloat($(this).val());
    if (!isNaN(val)) {
        $("#Price").val(getPriceString(val * 0.02));
        $("#ExtraDayPrice").val(getPriceString(val * 0.015));
        $('#WeekPrice').val(getPriceString(val * 0.1));
    }
});
```

Now instead, I'd like the `ExtraDayPrice` and `WeekPrice` to be depending on the `DayPrice` (which in turn is still depending on the entered  `ItemValue`). It must be like this: `ExtraDayPrice = 0,75 * DayPrice. WeekPrice = 5,3 * DayPrice`.
How do I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Save the dayPrice in a variable and just use that for further calculation .. right?

Answer (score 0):

You should use variables, assign those variables some value and then set the value of the input field to those variables. And since you need to update the other prices if the user wants to change the price manually you can use one change function, but just adjust the value used to calculate the other pricing fields.

```
$("#ItemValue, #Price").change(function () {
    var val = parseFloat($(this).val());
    if (!isNaN(val)) {
        //if the element clicked is ItemValue adjust val to be suggested dayPrice
        if(this.id == "ItemValue") {
            val *= 0.02;
        }
        //update the pricing elements
        updatePricing(val);
    }
});

function updatePricing(dayPrice) {
        var extraDayPrice = dayPrice * 0.015;
        var weekPrice = dayPrice * 0.1;

        $("#Price").val(getPriceString(dayPrice));
        $("#ExtraDayPrice").val(getPriceString(extraDayPrice));
        $('#WeekPrice').val(getPriceString(weekPrice));
}
```

Comment: Okay, that helps a bit. But what I would like, is to let the ExtraDayprice and WeekPrice be altered again, after changing the dayprice.
So: as a user, the first time I only enter the Item Value. Then, the code suggests a dayprice (plus extradayprice + weekprice). I don't agree with the dayprice, so I alter it. Then the extra dayprice and weekprice should be altered automatically.

Comment: hi @Adjit, unfortunately still no luck. It now says 'SyntaxError: missing formal parameter', this is for the line: function updatePricing(var dayPrice) {

Comment: Is there perhaps anyone else who might give an answer?

Comment: @Jonathan_S oh sorry, just take `var` out of the function parameters. Stupid syntax error.

Comment: @Jonathan_S no problem Jonathan. If you wouldn't mind accepting the answer that would be appreciated.